# Why does :read ++edit doesn't set fileformat, fileencoding?

Tags: file-formats

When comparing a buffer to it's on disk file, I regularly do (omitting the `diffthis`):

```
:botright vnew
:r ++edit #
```

According to https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#%3Aread the option ++edit should set the options of fileformat and fileencoding for the buffer to what regularly `:edit`ing `file` would give, unless I interpret the documentation wrong. Problem is, that none of the options of fileformat, fileencoding , ... get set for the `:vnew` buffer.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit (what I am expecting):** Assume I am editing a file minimal.yaml.  What I get with `:e minimal.yaml` is syntax highlighting for that file (could be json, whatever file format).

If another process changes that file on disk and I revisit that file in a `vnew | r ++edit #` buffer, that new buffer has no fileformat set, while I expect it to be of type yaml.

Comment: What fileformat, fileencoding are you getting and which were you expecting? Can you suggest a minimal reproducible example to illustrate the issue you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing `fileformat` (dos or unix) and `fileencoding` (utf-8, iso-8859-1) with `filetype` (yaml, c, python, tex, etc.)

With `++edit`, the `:read` command will set the former two (so you can read a Latin-1 file with CRLF line endings), but it won't trigger filetype detection.

It's hard to do so, since a lot of filetype detection depends on the file name and file extension and Vim will look at the buffer file name to get that information.

Assuming the purpose of using `:read` is to prevent modifications to the original file, consider just opening the file with `:edit` or `:view` (so all the filetype logic is triggered) and then setting options to prevent that buffer from ever saving back to the original file again.

See, for example, [`:help special-buffers`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#special-buffers), which tells you how to configure a scratch buffer:

> **scratch**: Contains text that can be discarded at any time. It is kept when closing the window, it must be deleted explicitly. Settings:
>
> ```
>     :setlocal buftype=nofile
>     :setlocal bufhidden=hide
>     :setlocal noswapfile
> ```
>
> The buffer name can be used to identify the buffer, if you give it a meaningful name.

Another approach to consider (possibly to combine with some of the scratch buffer support) is to set the buffer filename using the `:file` command (see [`:help :file_f`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Afile_f)), which you can use to tell Vim whenever the buffer is to be saved, you want it to try to write it to the file you specify instead.

Using some of these settings together can help you get the desired effect on the buffer you're creating.